# Scroll Progress Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, css-animations

I need to know how to make the scroll progress animation. It is not the normal scroll progress, but something different. I will give the link of the website and the screenshot of the particular section which has the animation that I'am looking for.

https://todoist.com/

This is the link of the website.

[image: 1]

I have attached the screenshot of the particular section in this website's homepage.

While scrolling the page, the scrolling get strucks in this section and this section scrolls within itself. After this section's scrolling is completed, the normal scrolling continues. I can see lot of tutorials for scroll progress bar, but not this particular style of animation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you solve the problem. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rexjbull/pen/RwRRezq)
Used AnimeJS + ScrollMagic.

Briefly:

```js
// Add scrollmagic controller
let controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// Add timeline
let tl1 = anime.timeline({autoplay: false});

//Then add some animation ... and

//Add first scrollmagic scene
let scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
 triggerElement: "#one",
 triggerHook: 0.5,
 reverse: false
})

//Play 
// Trigger animation timeline
.on("enter", function (event) {
 tl1.play();
})
 
.addTo(controller);
```